# Logs coming out in wrong directory in 64 bit builds (VC 2012)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm currently porting some 32 bit code to 64 bits (and also from
VS 2010 to VS 2012).  In order to be able to be able to generate
both 32 bits and 64 bits, I've put the following in a properties
file (included from all of the project files):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CALRoot Condition=" '$(CALRoot)' == '' ">..\..\..</CALRoot>
    <CALBuildSubDir Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'Win32' ">32bit</CALBuildSubDir>
    <CALBuildSubDir Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64' ">64bit</CALBuildSubDir>
    <CALBuildDir>$(CALRoot)\Build\VC12.0-$(CALBuildSubDir)\</CALBuildDir>
    <OutDir>$(CALBuildDir)$(ExtraBuildDir)$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
    <IntDir>$(CALBuildDir)$(ExtraBuildDir)$(Configuration)\obj\$(TargetName)\</IntDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

When I build with `Platform = Win32`, everything works the way
I expect: `CALUtils.{dll, exp,ilk,lib,pdb}` in
`Build\VC12.0-32bit\Debug`, and everything else (including
`CALUtils.log` in `Build\VC12.0-32bit\Debug\obj\CALUtils`.  When
I build with `Platform = x64`, however, `CALUtils.log` (and only
`CALUtils.log` ends up in a directory
`Build\VC12.0-\Debug\obj\CALUtils`.  Everything else is where
I'd expect (`Build\VC12.0-64bit\Debug` or
`Build\VC12.0-64bit\Debug\obj\CALUtils`); just this one file is
misplaced.

I've been unable to find any other place in the project file or
the properties files with the string `VC12.0-`, but maybe there
is something else coming into play.  Does anyone have any ideas
as to what additional variables could be involved in the name of
the log file, or why or how it is handled differently (and only
in 64 bit builds)?  Or is this a bug somewhere?ect file.)

Comment: If you preprocess the project, it may be easier to trace backwards to find how properties are being set.  (Run `msbuild /preprocess MyProject.vcxproj` with whatever other options are usually passed to the build, like Configuration and Platform).

Comment: @JamesMcNellis And how do I find out what options VS passes to msbuild?

Comment: Good question.  I would start by just passing `/p:SolutionDir={Path}`, `/p:Configuration=Release`, and `/p:Platform=x64` (where the "{Path}" is the path to the directory containing the .sln file that you usually open in the IDE).  That _should_ be sufficient.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Someone installed some new patches to Visual Studio overnight, and now I'm unable to reproduce the problem; everything ends up where it should.  So I guess the answer to my question is that it was a bug in Visual Studios.

Comment: Well, that's good to hear.  :-)